# Binomial Theorem Zero problem

Tags: number-theory

Hello I am trying to figure out how [Binomial theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcHyR.gif) formula works when the one of its elements is zero.

For example in the formula above if I choose $|a| = 2$ and $|b| = 0$ then $b^k$ does not look meaningful to me. Is there any rule about $a$ and $b$? Because when I choose one of them zero, I can't deal with the equation or is there even a special case for that?

Comment: When one of the two elements is $0$ say $b$ the theorem is the trivial identity $a^n=a^n$

Comment: Why doesn't it look meaningful? $0^k= 0$ for $k>0$ and *in most cases* $0^0 = 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you simply have $(a+0)^n = a^n$. This also follows from the formula as all terms $0^k = 0$ except when $k=0$.